# Qt(C++) считывание данных с веб страницы

Tags: c++, qt

Как в `Qt` можно реализовать считывание определенной информации со страницы сайта? Какие классы для этого нужно подключать, хотелось бы посмотреть на примерный код. Не помешают и ссылочки на материалы по этой теме.

Как возможно будет считать информацию которой нет в `html` коде, например, [тут](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Chroma%202%20Case%20Key): при наведении курсора на графики появляются числа, как можно считать эти числа?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Qt имеется QtWebKit - компонент, реализующий функциональность браузера с поддержкой JS. Так что ваша задача состоит в исследовании скриптового функционала страницы при помощи, например, FireBug, а затем вызова этих js-методов посредством WebKit.

Вызов js:

```
QWebView::page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript( "some_js_function()" );
```

Comment: в QWebView дальше mainFrame() никаких функций не показывает, в чем проблема подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: @АмирАфендин заголовочник QWebFrame не забыли?

Comment: Точно.Благодарю :)

Comment: А как мне прописать этот 
<a class="menuitem supernav username" href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/afendinamir/home/" data-tooltip-type="selector" data-tooltip-content=".submenu_username">Oiᗡ</a>
 элемент в findFirstElement?SPAN[class=menuitem supernav username] не работает

Comment: @АмирАфендин из вашей просьбы мало что понятно, переформулируйте.

Comment: Нужно таким QWebElement e = browser->page()->mainFrame()->findFirstElement("SPAN[class=]"); образом получить элемент со страницы.Элементы с одним аргументом наподобие span class="test" легко считывает.Но  мне нужно считать span class="pulldown global_action_link" id="account_pulldown" onclick="ShowMenu( this, 'account_dropdown', 'right', 'bottom', true ) и там одним аргументом не получается

Comment: то есть вы понимаете это один элемент который мне нужно считать но в нем много аргументов

Comment: @АмирАфендин Изучите документацию на синтаксис выбора в CSS2 https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/selector.html#q1

Именно этот синтаксис использует findFirstElement

Comment: был на этой странице и не только там, перелопатил все варианты но не могу считать элемент span где больше одного аргумента.

Comment: @АмирАфендин на самом деле, вам стоит выделить это в отдельный вопрос - в этом вопросе это оффтопик.
А вот возможное решение  "Here, the selector matches all SPAN elements whose "hello" attribute has exactly the value "Cleveland" and whose "goodbye" attribute has exactly the value "Columbus":

SPAN[hello="Cleveland"][goodbye="Columbus"] { color: blue; }"